# What does ExternalServicesEnabled tenant property do?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, administration, governance

`ExternalServicesEnabled` tenant setting is set to $true defailt. It means that "External Services" are enabled. What would happen exactly if set ExternalServicesEnabled to $false to disable "Extrnal Services"?

What does this setting control exactly?

This is the [description from Microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/set-spotenant?view=sharepoint-ps), but it is not that helpful:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you disable it, some external services such as GitHub, FaceBook and so on will not be used with office 365 tenant,here is an article about authorize external services for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/auth-external-add-ins